# Saving cells from MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, file-io, save, cell

I have a cell array which contains 7 matrices of varying column and length size. I have tried using the function ['dlmcell'](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25387-write-cell-array-to-text-file) which is downloadable from the MATLAB website but is says "Text exceeds maximum line length of 25000 characters for Command Window Display".

I have looked at a few other examples of saving the arrays but none of them seem to be able to deal with the structure of the cell or the size of the file.

The main aim for me is to save the cell so that I may later import it. Is there no specific format that MATLAB uses (like .mat for example) to store the cell arrays?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just using `save` like normal works for me:

```
>> cellarray = {1:1000; 'my cell array'}

cellarray = 

    [1x1000 double]
    'my cell array'

>> save('cellarray','cellarray')
   %# filename---^   ^--- variable name
>> clear all
>> load('cellarray')
>> cellarray

cellarray = 

    [1x1000 double]
    'my cell array'
```

`cellarray.mat` is saved as a matfile in the current directory.  You can load it just as easily, with `load`.  Am I missing something?  Is it more complicated than this?

Comment: For some strange reason it was giving me errors when I previously used this simple function but now I restarted my PC it is working. I think it had something to do with my memory being maxed out!

Thank you!